# What protocol does an app server and nginx communicate through?

Tags: nginx, tcp, webserver, protocols

**Background:**
Imagine you have a web app with this architecture: A Node App Server(Koa) and an Nginx Web Server in front.

**Scenario:**
Client browser makes a request to Server. It gets picked up by nginx and sent through to app server and app server responses back to nginx and nginx response back to client.

**Question:**
From this interaction, What are the protocols at each request and response? Do you configure them, is it http/1 or 1.1 or 2? is it tcp/ip

Browser Request: TCP/IP ???
Nginx Request: ???
App Server Response: ???
Nginx Request: ???

Comment: From client to NGINX do you have a exchange to upgrade or downgrade. If you enable HTTP2, http2 will be used to NGINX and Client in most cases, cases that be supported by browser. Behind the scenes, as a proxy, i don't know if you will be use HTTP 1.1, HTTP 2....

Comment: Yeah as a reverse proxy I'm wondering what the communication from nginx to app server and response back to nginx. From more research it would seem nginx communicates with: http(s), FastCGI, SCGI, and uwsgi, or memcached but I wonder what it expects from app server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What protocol does an app server and nginx communicate through?

Whatever protocol you've configured.

> Imagine you have a web app with this architecture: A Node App Server(Koa) and an Nginx Web Server in front.

Your Koa app is going to use HTTP.  Therefore, HTTP is used between Nginx and your app server.

> Browser Request: TCP/IP ???

HTTP is always ran over TCP.  The browser will use whichever version of HTTP is supported by itself and the server.

> Do you configure them, is it http/1 or 1.1 or 2?

Yes, you configure it.  Although, Node.js doesn't support HTTP/1.0 properly.  And, HTTP/2 is *typically* terminated by your web server (Nginx in this example).  So, it's *typical* that HTTP/1.1 is used between Nginx and your Node.js app server.  This, obviously, can change if you change it.

Comment: Small amendment are there any advantages (performance bumps) to using http2 between nginx and app server?

Comment: @MatthewHarwood If Nginx and the application are not on the same host, it's possible that usage of HTTP/2 would be more efficient thanks to its improved pipelining of requests/responses.  Otherwise, I have a hunch (but have not tested) that HTTP/1.1 would be more efficient, due to the complexity of HTTP/2 and that the libraries for it in Node.js haven't had the years of rigorous optimizing yet.  You should test it in your specific situation though, as there are a lot of factors.